# Django don't show first image in template

Tags: html, django

I'm new to Django and I need to show all images inside different folders in the HTML file.

In views.py I have something like this:

```
python
        template = loader.get_template('index.html')
        context = {
            'images': imm,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

`imm` is a variable that contains path of some images.
In the template I have:

```
html
<div class="row">
   {{ images }}
   {% for image in images %}
   <div class="column">
       <img src="{{ image }}" style="width:100%" >
       {{ image }}
       </div>
   {% endfor %}

</div>
```

In here the first image is not showed while the others are OK. It is not a problem of the image itself because i tried to change the order of the images in images list.

`{{ image }}` returns the right path of the image but when I see the code through the browser the first image has path "".

{{ images }} is:

```
['/path/000000000115.jpg', '/path/000000000139.jpg', '/path/000000000140.jpg', '/path/000000000632.jpg', '/path/000000000724.jpg', '/path/000000000776.jpg', '/path/000000000785.jpg']
```

I'm not understanding what is wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved adding:

```
HTML
<img src="" style="width:100% display:none">
```

before the

```
{% for image in images %}
```